# How to return multiple rows with repeating non-unique query values in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table 'mat' with columns x,y,data, where (x,y) is the multi-column primary key, so the table contains data in matrix form. The problem is how to select multiple rows when I have a "vector" of key pairs and there can be repeating pairs:

```
SELECT x,y,data FROM mat WHERE (x,y) IN ((0,0),(0,0),(1,1));
```

quite obviously returns

```
x | y | data
--+---+-----
0 | 0 | 5
1 | 1 | 7
```

whereas I would need:

```
x | y | data
--+---+-----
0 | 0 | 5
0 | 0 | 5
1 | 1 | 7
```

I could loop the key pairs from outside (in c++/whatever code) to get the correct data but there's a major performance degradation and that's quite critical. Any suggestions? Is it possible? Help appreciated!

Comment: A Primary Key is unique and cannot contain duplicates. Your {x,y} pairs contain duplicates and cannot be a PK.

Comment: please either change "primary keys" to smth else in the topic (eg to "values") or remove "non-unique" from it - otherwise it sounds faulty

Comment: The primary key itself is unique in the table but I have a data vector of values (x0,y0)...(xn,yn) where there can be duplicates

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a `JOIN` for this

```
SELECT mat.x,mat.y,data 
FROM mat 
JOIN 
(
   SELECT 0 x, 0 y
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 0 x, 0 y
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 x, 1 y
) t ON t.x = mat.x and t.y = mat.y
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=36638142b292e833e1e82d590cc56ed3)

The `IN` is just evaluated to `true`/`false`/`unknown` for each row, it can not multiply your data.

Answer (score 1):

Radim has the right idea.  I prefer this syntax:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mat m JOIN 
     (VALUES (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)) v(x, y)
     ON m.x = v.x and m.y = v.y;
```